# Performing git merge in atom editor without the terminal

Tags: git, version-control, atom-editor

[image]

My favorite editor [atom](https://atom.io/) has nicely integrated adding, committing, pushing and pulling with git. But where is the merge function? Is it possible to do this without the terminal? With atom out of the box functionality? Or with an atom package?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is no merge function in Atom out of the box. Someone had raised an [issue](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/1509) last year and it's not resolved.

There's a 3rd party package that lets you do this, though - https://atom.io/packages/git-control

Warning: I haven't tested it, and they themselves state that there might be a few issues.

Comment: Unfortunately git-control does not work for me, throws an exception when trying to start it: https://github.com/jacogr/atom-git-control/issues/259